# Physical interpretation of Robin's boundary conditions for Poisson equation

Tags: electromagnetism

i want to know the physical interpretation of Robin's boundary conditions for Poisson equation on $\Omega=]0,a[$x$]0,b[$

$-\Delta u =f $ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}+\alpha u =g $ on $\partial\Omega$ with g$\in L^2(\partial\Omega)and$  $ \alpha(x,y)>0 $